# Continue Visual Studio 2015 installation of features

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I recently added the required components for creating universal apps for Windows 10 in Visual Studio 2015. However, I didn't have the time to finish the installation. The installation was cancelled successfully and I was met with a message like this: '52 of 58 components was successfully installed.'.

I didn't get any information on how to continue this process. Is there any way of continuing the installation? I've tried looking around in Visual Studio 2015, and I can't find any place to do this. I also tried downloading the emulators again, because that's the one that didn't finish. I then get a message which says I need to uninstall an already installed version of the Windows 10 emulators.

The original installation was triggered through Visual Studio when I tried to choose 'Universal'. It didn't have any of the templates available and said it needed to install the SDK. I was then met with the sweet [checkbox GUI (it looks just like this)](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-36-44/4113.setup.png) where I chose what to install.

Is there any way to get back into this GUI, or, are the any way of continuing this installation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you download the installer again and run it, there should be a "modify" option I believe. From there you can add features you wish via the checkbox screen you mentioned.

UPDATE: This can be remedied by using "change" within programs and features. From then you can modify the installation to add necessary features. (See comments for more details)

Comment: Problem is I don't know where the installer were downloaded to, nor the name of it. Visual Studio downloaded it 'internally' somewhere on the file system. I also thought there would be a modify option. Maybe I can modify Visual Studio from within Programs and Features.

Comment: It was surprisingly easy. I went to 'Programs and Features' -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise -> Change -> (Installer comes on screen) Modify -> 'Add the features you want'. The packages that was missing was correct.

Comment: That's new on me. Usually when I download Visual Studio it ends up with the name "vs_community" and its in my "downloads" folder. I'm sorry I could not be of more assistance. I'm glad you were able to get it working through control panel though!

Comment: I meant you should update your anseer based on what we found out from the comments. 

Comment: Ok :) I edited my answer! Still a little new to posting here. I appreciate it!